# mysql - split list seperated by comma to a list of INTs

Tags: mysql, sql

```
question:

+-----------+-------------------------+
|question id|          help_ref       |
+-----------+-------------------------+
|     1     |      1001,1002,1004     |
+-----------+-------------------------+
|     2     |      1005,1002,1001     |
+-----------+-------------------------
help:

+--------------------+
|help_id|  text      |
+--------------------+
| 1001 | sjfdisfidif |
+--------------------+
| 1002 |  dfdjdjdjjd |
+--------------------+
| 1003 | blafdsjdidjd|
+--------------------+
| 1004 | somethibngjd|
+--------------------+
```

what I'm trying to accomplish is to get help id's from the help_ref

what iv'e done so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM questions AS a
JOIN `help` AS b on find_in_set(b.`help_id`,a.`help_ref`) >0
WHERE b.`help_id` IN (1001,1002) // IM TRYING TO CHANGE THAT TO THE help_ref value
AND `question_id` = 1
```

So how can I change the 1001,1002 values to the actual help_ref string?

expected result:

```
SELECT *
FROM questions AS a
JOIN `help` AS b on find_in_set(b.`help_id`,a.`help_ref`) >0
WHERE b.`help_id` IN (a.`help_ref`)
AND `question_id` = 1

help_id | text
1001    | sjfdisfidif
1002    | dfdjdjdjjd
1004    | somethibngjd
```

Comment: Could you show us your expect result?

Comment: edited, thank you @D-Shih

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT h.*
FROM help h
INNER JOIN question q
    ON FIND_IN_SET(h.help_id, q.help_ref) > 0 AND q.question_id = 1;
```

### Demo